How do you extract good presentations from monads?
Suppose you have a finitary monad $F:\text{Set}\to \text{Set}$; this is, to be clear, a functor along with the information of a multiplication natural transformation $\mu: F\circ F \to F$ and a unit transformation $\eta: 1_{\text{Set}} \to F$ which have to make various sensible diagrams commute and the finitary part just means it preserves filtered colimits.
It's a fact that universal algebra is essentially entirely captured by the theory of finitary monads, in the sense that normally you list a bunch of universally quantified identities in a first-order language and look at their models and these categories of models are exactly those obtainable as the Eilenberg-Moore algebras of finitary monads. The approach given by listing axioms can be seen as presenting a monad but monads don't come with a canonical presentation.
My question is: what's a good way of extracting a good list of axioms (i.e. a good presentation) from a monad?
I'm not necessarily looking for a general algorithm which produces, say, the presentation with the smallest number of axioms, I just want some general rules of thumb about what do/where to look to get a nice presentation. For example, suppose you're given the free group monad: how could you plausibly get the group axioms from that?

It depends where your monad comes from. In the example you've given, the monad is defined using a presentation, so the question is somewhat tautological. Do you have an example where this isn't the case?

Every monoid $M$ induces such a monad (whose algebras are $M$-sets), so this is at least as hard as asking "what's a good way of extracting a good presentation of a monoid"? And in this level of generality I don't know a better answer than "well, it depends a lot on how you're constructing or given $M$."

@varkor: here's a concrete example. There's a finitary monad whose $n$-ary operations (this corresponds to $F([n])$) are given by $n$-ary convex linear combinations; algebras of this monad are "convex spaces" and include e.g. spaces of probability distributions and convex subsets of real vector spaces. This monad is generated by its binary operations but the resulting presentation is pretty annoying and inelegant to my mind and I don't know a better one. Actually I think this description is the cleanest one.

I agree with Qiaochu. There is not much you can do except for going through the general proof that monads correspond to Lawvere theories (see for example the appendix here). Also notice that nothing guarantees you finitely many operations or finitely many axioms.

@MartinBrandenburg Do you know any condition on a monad which leads to it being finitely axiomatisable? I know that being finitary is supposed to be the same as it having a presentation with finite-arity operations.
